# How to use X-Forwarded-Proto in Nginx Webserver

Tags: nginx

I have set `X-Forwarded-Proto` to the header. But Nginx as my webserver not using it and always assume the scheme is HTTP, even though I set the `X-Forwarded-Proto` to HTTPS

How to set Nginx to use X-Forwarded-Proto?

**Note: Nginx here as a webserver not a reverse proxy**

Answer (score 1):

https://serverfault.com/a/875278/
is the clever way.

Since no https traffic can ever hit my receving vhost though (firewalled off from public net), I've instead set this alongside my fastcgi setup;

```
fastcgi_param HTTPS 'on';
```